# Email to Case inbound mesasge

Tags: apex, email2case

Is there a possible way to capture the inbound message of Email to Case 
salesforce the must manipulate it first.

Thank you so much for this matter.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a trigger the [EmailMessage](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_emailmessage.htm) object to handle emails from Email to Case.

```
trigger handleEmail on EmailMessage (before insert) {
  // Do stuff here
}
```

Comment: Is there a reference for this sir

Comment: @JohnRegada The link to the EmailMessage object shows you the fields and possible values. Basically, you're just looking for messages that are inbound (Inbound == true) and whatever else you need to know.

Answer (score 1):

For that purpose you need to implement `Messaging.InboundEmailHandler` and use

```
global Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(Messaging.inboundEmail email,  Messaging.InboundEnvelope env)
```

For more information, refer [Using the InboundEmail Object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_inbound_using.htm)

Here is a sample code might help you

```
global class CreateInboundCase implements Messaging.InboundEmailHandler 
{

  global Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(Messaging.inboundEmail email, 
                                                       Messaging.InboundEnvelope env){

    Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailResult();

    List<String> toAddresses = email.toAddresses; 

    try 
    {
       if(toAddresses.size()>0)
       {    
            Case newCase = new Case();
            newCase.Description =  email.plainTextBody;
            newCase.SuppliedEmail = email.fromAddress;
            newCase.SuppliedName = email.fromName;
            newCase.Subject = email.subject;
            newCase.Origin = 'Email';                
            newCase.status  = 'New';
            newCase.Ownerid = '<assign OwnerId>';

            if(email.subject.contains('Credit'))
            {
                //put your logic here.

            }
       }

        //perform case record insert operation.
        Database.SaveResult[] srList = Database.insert(newCase, true);

        List<EmailMessage> lstEmailMessage = new List<EmailMessage>();

        // Iterate through each returned result and create Email object for attaching to Case.
        for (Database.SaveResult sr : srList) {
            if (sr.isSuccess()) 
            {
                // Operation was successful, so get the ID of the record that was processed
                System.debug('Successfully inserted case id: ' + sr.getId());

                EmailMessage emailMsgObj = new EmailMessage();
                emailMsgObj.HtmlBody =  email.htmlBody;
                emailMsgObj.TextBody = email.plainTextBody;
                emailMsgObj.FromAddress = email.fromAddress;                
                emailMsgObj.FromName = email.fromName;
                emailMsgObj.Subject = email.subject;
                emailMsgObj.Incoming = true;
                emailMsgObj.ParentId = sr.getId();

                lstEmailMessage.add(emailMsgObj);               
            }
        }
        Database.SaveResult[] srEmailList = Database.insert(lstEmailMessage, true);

        List<Attachment> lstAttachment = new List<Attachment>();

        //if attachment exists in inbound email those to be attached into Email record.
        for (Database.SaveResult sr : srEmailList) 
        {
            if (sr.isSuccess()) 
            {
                if (email.binaryAttachments != null && email.binaryAttachments.size() > 0) {
                    for (integer i = 0 ; i < email.binaryAttachments.size() ; i++) {
                        Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
                        attachment.ParentId = sr.getId();
                        attachment.Name = email.binaryAttachments[i].filename;
                        attachment.Body = email.binaryAttachments[i].body;
                        lstAttachment.add(attachment);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Database.insert(lstAttachment, true);
    }
   catch (Exception e) {
       //handle it properly.
       result.success = false;
       return result;
   }

   result.success = true;
   return result;
}
```

Comment: Hi Sir do I need to code the Inbound messsage if I use the Email to Case ?

Comment: Is it possible to use Inbound message to Email to Case ? or I need to use the Email Services for it ... I dont want  to use the Email Services for it needs to register the email unlike to Email to Case I just need to use the link to send the email

Comment: You didn't specify what your usecase is. If you really extract the email and want to update any case attribute you can do that.

Comment: I need to capture the Inbound message of Email to Case in order to check if the subject and if the subject contains 'Credit' it will automatically forward the email to other email.

Comment: I have added my sample code, you have refactor based on your need